# Access vertices' positions of a rigged model after rotating its joint angle in Panda3D

Tags: opengl, mesh, vertex, panda3d

Hi, everyone,
I've run into a problem when manipulating a rigged mesh model in Panda3D. I loaded a mesh model which has an armature modifier consisting of two adjoint bones( one for the palm, one for a collection of four fingers, namely index, middle, ring and little finger ), which looks like this [original unchanged hand model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNys8.png); then I transform the latter bone ( joint ) to fold the four fingers inward, using actor's 'controlJoint' method. Codes here :

```
self.handActor = Actor( r'/d/3DModels/TestHand.egg' )
self.handJoint1 = self.handActor.controlJoint( None,
                                               'modelRoot',
                                               'Bone1'
                                               )
self.handJoint2 = self.handActor.controlJoint( None,
                                               'modelRoot',
                                               'Bone2'
                                               )
self.handJoint2.setP( 90 )
```

Then I accessed the vertex info of the the current transformed mesh, with code like this below :

```
geomNodeCollection = self.handActor.findAllMatches( '**/+GeomNode' )
geomNodePath = geomNodeCollection[ 0 ]
geomNode = geomNodePath.node()
geom = geomNode.getGeom( 0 )
vData = geom.getVertexData()
reader_vertex = GeomVertexReader( vData, 'vertex' )
reader_normal = GeomVertexReader( vData, 'normal' )

vertexList = list()
normalList = list()

for i in xrange( 2000 ) :

    vertex = reader_vertex.getData3f()
    normal = reader_normal.getData3f()

    vertexList.append( vertex )
    normalList.append( normal )
```

Then I marked each of these positions with an smiley sphere, expecting to see a cloud of these smileys positioned just fitting around the deformed hand. However, I got a point cloud of the original hand shape, which is flattened, like this :[deformed hand model and vertices obtained shown a point cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwTXt.png)
   Any idea about how to obtain the vertices positions exactly matching the deformed hand mesh? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call `animateVertices` on the `GeomVertexData`, such as:

```
vData = geom.getVertexData().animateVertices(True, Thread.getCurrentThread())
```

Panda will automatically cache the animated GeomVertexData.

Comment: Thanks a lot, rdb! You are right. I tried as you suggested and it worked. Apart from this, I found that a call of "PartBundle.forceUpdate()" right after rotating any joint is neccessary also.

Comment: Yes, normally placing the character in the scene makes Panda automatically call `character.update()`, but if you extract the geometry yourself then you need to call it yourself.
If you liked my answer consider clicking the accept button to accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks! It's done! Functions like these are truely useful, but takes time to find exploring throught Panda3D's documentation. Lucky to got an answer from an expert like you, thanks again!